# ACPu cache with a cron job

Tags: cron, apc

My sites homepage first time access load time is between 5-8 seconds.

Once I'm on my website all pages load fast. And if I access the homepage directly again it will load instantly.

I set up a `warmcache.sh` script to have just the hompage cached.

Looking at my `apc.php` dashboard, the cache is flushed after some minutes after I have accessed my site. Yet the load time is still low, even after 5 minutes accessing my homepage. But I don't know for how long?

How often should I set the `warmcachach.sh` to run in a cron job to keep the load time low for the homepage?

The question is that I don't know how long it's kept in cache, because the `apc.php` dashboard indicates that cache has been flushed after some minutes and the only change in the diagram shows:

> Used: 32.2 KBytes (0.1%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the TTL parameter in your `apc.ini` configuration file:

> apc.gc_ttl    3600

A value of `3600` means it's being cached and stored for 1 hour. So you can set your cron job to run every one hour.